# How to verify many variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to check the state of many variables in ruby.

But more elegantly than

```
if (@op.wash == true || @op.wash == false) && (@op.communication == true || @op.communication == false)
```

It should look like this :

```
if [@op.wash, @op.communication] == [false, nil]
```

But this is not working. Any ideas to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"? This is valid ruby and it even evaluates to true in certain conditions.

Comment: Hi @SergioTulentsev, it's a condition. If all this variables are equal to nil or false then run something

Comment: I don't think he was asking what it's supposed to do, which is fairly obvious. I think he was asking what specifically isn't working (in general this is not how you'd compare multiple values in Ruby). "More elegantly" meaning... what, exactly? I mean, if all you care about is truthy/falsey then stop using the redundant `== true` etc. It's readable and meaningful.

Comment: I @DaveNewton, thanks for your answer. How you compare multiples variables ?

Comment: `if (@op.wash || !@op.wash) && (@op.communication || !@op.communication)` which seems... completely pointless. Which makes it look like you're missing an abstraction, and this should be wrapped up in business rule helper methods.

Comment: @DaveNewton: yeah, they made up that line in a hurry, I think. Should be nil instead of true. But who knows... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If all this variables are equal to nil or false then run something

It's pretty straightforward

```
if [@op.wash, @op.communication].all?{|v| [false, nil].include?(v) }
```

or

```
if ([@op.wash, @op.communication] - [false, nil]).empty?
```

or maybe a few dozen other ways. Block-less `.none?` probably can't be beaten, in this exact scenario:

```
if [@op.wash, @op.communication].none?
```